# Echo php in string

Tags: php, arrays, string, echo

I don't know how to explain it very well because i'm a php noob, but I'm trying to echo title (that i want to select from the database) in $meta['track']['title']

```
<?php
$meta['neuwsarch']['title'] = "Title";
$meta['neuwsarch']['keywords'] = "key, key2, key3";
$meta['neuwsarch']['description'] = "description";

$data = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM news WHERE seo='".$seo."' AND ID='".$ID."'");
$news = mysql_fetch_assoc($data) ;

$meta['news']['title'] = "ECHO TITLE IN HERE";
$meta['news']['keywords'] = "kwd1, kwd2, kwd3";
$meta['news']['description'] = "trackert";
?>
```

Comment: You may use `$meta['news']['title'] = $news ["title"];`

Comment: So you want to make an associative array from db?

Comment: @zipser thanks for the reply. I already tried that but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

[echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) simply displays a value or string to the screen. So if you wanted to display the value of $news['title'] to the screen use echo $news['title'].

What you are trying to do is assign the array element $meta['news']['title'] with the value of 'title' from your SQL query, which you would do like:

```
$meta['news']['title'] = $news['title'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I already tried that, it doesn't work

Comment: @Yesyah one of reason it may not work is query return 0 results. You need to echo your query then run it through DB shell/GUI to verify if every thing is ok with query. After all we do not see how $seo and $ID is set.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to iterate over the result set returned by MySQL.

You can have your last 3 lines in a while loop that iterates over the results returned from `mysql_fetch_array()`.

And, start using PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it, I just added this to the top of the line:

```
$ID = intval ($_GET['ID']);
$seo =($_GET['seo']);
```

and used this:

```
$meta['news']['title'] = $news['title'];
```

thanks for the answers guys!